# Error with deleting 1 row after doing some checks

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem trying to delete an entire row using the code as below:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim test1row As Long, test1 As Range, firstrowtodelete As Long

    test1row = 1

    Do 
        Set test1 = Sheets("Sheet1")l.Cells(test1row,1)

        If test1 <> "actest" Or test1 <> "dctest" Then
            firstrowtodelete = test1row
            Rows(test1row).Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
            Exit Do
        End If

        test1row = test1row + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

The error is with `Rows(test1row).Select`.  It deletes the row even if it is "actest" or "dctest". If you know why do share with me! thanks! :)

Comment: user1204868: This is an incorrect way to use a loop. What if the condition is not met? You will get an error when test1row reaches 65536(Excel 2003) or 1048576(Excel 2007/2010) :) You might want to use a For loop? Also this method is incorrect when you want to delete multiple rows. i.e delete all rows which match the above condition.

Comment: hi, thanks for you advise.. At the moment i just need to delete 1 row..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

The first problem is on this line:

```
Set test1 = Sheets("Sheet1")l.Cells(test1row,1)
```

It should be:

```
Set test1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(test1row, 1)
```

And the other problem is here:

```
If test1 <> "actest" Or test1 <> "dctest" Then
```

It should be this:

```
If test1 <> "actest" And test1 <> "dctest" Then
```

Your `If` statement would always be true. Using the `And` operator will give you a true value only when the cell's value isn't "actest" *and* it isn't "dctest" which is presumably the desired behavior.

Here is the complete working code:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim test1row As Long, test1 As Range, firstrowtodelete As Long

    test1row = 1

    Do
        Set test1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(test1row, 1)

        If test1 <> "actest" And test1 <> "dctest" Then
            firstrowtodelete = test1row
            Rows(test1row).Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
            Exit Do
        End If

        test1row = test1row + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: hi, i have 1 question.. what if dc test is not around.. that means the test will not work.. right? but i still wants to delete the row..

Answer (score 1):

Your `If` test is flawed.  It will always be true.

Comment: hi, do u have any suggestions of what i can do?

Comment: hi, i think i have found a way using 'Else'. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: @user1204868: See my answer for more details.